# Realm Xamarin LINQ Select

Tags: linq, xamarin, realm

Is there a way to restrict the "columns" returned from a Realm Xamarin LINQ query?

For example, if I have a `Customer` RealmObject and I want a list of all customer names, do I have to query `All<Customer>` and then enumerate the results to build the names list? That seems cumbersome and inefficient. I am not seeing anything in the docs. Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks!

Comment: Selecting just the names, doesn't work why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that Realm is an object based store. In a RDBMS like Sqlite, restricting the return results to a sub-set of "columns" of an "record" makes sense, but in an object store, you would be removing attributes from the original class and thus creating a new dynamic class to then instantiate these new classes as objects.

Thus is you want just a List of strings representing the customer names you can do this:

```
List<string> names = theRealm.All<Customer>().ToList().Select(customer => customer.Name).ToList();
```

**Note:** That you take the `Realm.All<>` results to a `List` *first* and then using a Linq `Select` "filter" just the property that you want. Using a `.Select` directly on a `RealmResults` is not currently supported (`v0.80.0`).

If you need to return a complex type that is a subset of attributes from the original `RealObject`, assuming you have a matching POCO, you can use:

```
var custNames = theRealm.All<Customer>().ToList().Select((Customer c) => new Name() { firstName = c.firstName, lastName = c.lastName } );
```

Remember, once you convert a `RealmResult` to a static list of POCOs you do lose the *liveliness* of using `RealmObject`s.

Personally I avoid doing this whenever possible as Realm is so fast that using a `RealmResult` and thus the `RealObject`s directly is more efficient on processing time and memory overhead then converting those to POCOs everytime you need to new list...

Comment: Just to build up on that, there are very few scenarios where you'll want to get a subset of realm object's properties (I imagine, for sending to a server or building a concatenated string). In most cases, you can use the complete `Customer` object, as returned by `All<Customer>`, without any performance implication.

Comment: @NikolaIrinchev Totally agree, and in the case of a concatenated string, say First and Last name, using a readonly property that is tagged `[Ignored]`in your `RealmObject` that performs the concatenation is still more performant than converting First+Last name to a `List` of strings or POCOs....